# can we use php to define if the cookie has been set if that cookie is not from the same domain?

Tags: php, cookies

I know that if the cookie was made from my domain I can just use something like this

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
  echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["user"] . "!<br />";
else
  echo "Welcome guest!<br />";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

what if the cookie was from different domain and I don't know what is the cookie name or don't have control on it lets assume that website `http://cookieprovider.com` if you visit you will get a cookie store for one week then if the visitors comes back to my website and I want to see if they have the cookie set on their browser or not if not send them back or give them a message warn that the cookie isn't set yet and need to go back again to refresh or whatever and when they have the cookie will give them a welcome message and so on.

will this be possible?

if not so that I can see other solution just wanted to make sure.

Comment: You want to see if a cookie from another domain is set? I smell something fishy, here.

Comment: @JamWaffles nothing to be hide what I'm trying to achieve is that there is a website that use to provide videos links so they must visit once to watch the videos so they have to go and visit the site first so that they can watch the video on my site so sometime my visitors complain that they can't watch so I just want to have some message to notify them that they must visit the site first so that they able to watch that is all I'm trying to do.

Comment: Oh ok. No disrespect; SO sees quite a few questions that are rather poor attempts at hiding a malicious purpose. Yours is, obviously, not one of them :-)

Comment: @JamWaffles thanks for understanding and I'm now understood that this is not possible because of the security reason :)

Comment: No problem. I wish you luck in finding a solution to your problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali,

For obvious security reasons, you can't read a cookie that belongs to another domain. You can do it across sub-domains though.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't. You can't set nor get sessions from another domains